# Different methods for update fields by name etc

Tags: powershell

At this moments in my powershell script i use for update fields this code:

```
$Field.["Home City"];
$Field.Update();
```

I used display name of column buy when i creted that field in SP i used name like "HomeCity" and afert data i chane it on "Home City".
Sometimes i must chanege that disp name for ex.  "My Home City" and after that i must change it in code. So i wonder if how use i code the name of field that i used in first place. 
I know when i changed name of Title for ex. "Nazwa towaru" i can use:

```
$Field.Title;
$Field.Update();
```

But it dont work for ma ex. HomeCity. Can i use the default name of custom name fields before i change it? And how ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Field["HomeCity"] = "Text"
$Field.Update();
```

Use **Internal Name** of a field instead of **Display Name** as @Sunil and @Melad said.

Answer (score 0):

While working with list columns in SharePoint its recommended to use Internal Name of the columns of the list instead of using Display Name And the Internal Name does not changes if change the display name.

The easiest trick to see what the **Internal Name** is (to me), to go to **List Settings**, and then click on the **column name** in which you are interested. On the Change Column page, the URL will end in something like:

```
/_layouts/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B37920121%2D19B2%2D4C77%2D92FF%2D8B3E07853114%7D&Field=Home%5Fx0020%5FCity
```

[You can refer the link](http://sympmarc.com/2009/12/11/staticname-versus-displayname-on-sharepoint-lists/)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sunil sahu mentioned in his answer it's much better to use Internal Name of an column/Field...

```
$list.fields | select InternalName
```